# Identify first block in a pandas series based on switching values

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following pandas series:

```py
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
```

I want to identify the first block of 1 values. The block starts when 0 switches to 1 for the first time and ends when it switches back (don't has to). The rest should just equal zero. One restriction: no iteration allowed, only pure pandas.

Expected output:

```py
s_new = pd.Series([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify the first block of `1` by first identifying the `1`s that follow a `0`, computing the [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and keeping the block equal to `1`:

```
out = s.where(s.diff().eq(1).cumsum().eq(1), 0)
```

Output:

```
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     0
8     0
9     0
10    0
11    0
12    0
13    0
14    0
15    0
dtype: int64
```

Intermediates:

```
    s  diff  eq(1)  cumsum
0   0   NaN  False       0
1   0   0.0  False       0
2   0   0.0  False       0
3   1   1.0   True       1
4   1   0.0  False       1
5   1   0.0  False       1
6   1   0.0  False       1
7   0  -1.0  False       1
8   1   1.0   True       2
9   0  -1.0  False       2
10  0   0.0  False       2
11  1   1.0   True       3
12  1   0.0  False       3
13  1   0.0  False       3
14  0  -1.0  False       3
15  1   1.0   True       4
```